# MvcContrib Grid - AutoGenerateColumns possible with complex objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I like [MvcContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid)'s [AutoGenerateColumns](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/04/27/mvccontrib-grid-part-7-auto-generated-columns/) feature, however it only seems to work with simple objects.  Is it possible to get it to traverse the properties of a complex object? Or is it neccesary to do this manually with `column.For()`?

An example would be a User object that has an Address object as one of its properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  The grid only loops through a single layer of properties.  MVCContrib Grid won't recursively drill down into your object.

If you look at the [the source](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c67ded0e8f8d#src%2fMVCContrib%2fUI%2fGrid%2fAutoColumnBuilder.cs):

```
        foreach(var property in modelMetadata.Properties)
        {
            if(!property.ShowForDisplay)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var column = For(PropertyToExpression(property));

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(property.DisplayName))
            {
                column.Named(property.DisplayName);
            }

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(property.DisplayFormatString))
            {
                column.Format(property.DisplayFormatString);
            }
        }
```